# How do I configure a specific cell in a UITableView?

Tags: iphone, arrays, uitableview, configuration, cells

I have a number of different cells in my table view which are populated via an array. I then in the 'cellForRowAtIndex' configure the cells to make them look correct. For example...

```
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"STHeitiSC-Medium" size:18.0];
```

However this affects every cell in the table view, I want to have specific configurations & attributes for specific cells. Does anyone know how this can be achieved?

Thanks!

UPDATE:

Just thought I'd mention that I ended up finding this which was quite helpful:
[Changing specific cells in uitableview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7750795/changing-specific-cells-in-uitableview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` has a `indexPath` parameter (of type `NSIndexPath`). When you call `[indexPath row]` you will get the index of the row you are currently loading. I guess you could use this value to set the correct font for a specific row?

Comment: It's important to remember also that cells are _reused_, so you need to set the font every time, not just for the "special" cell.